# Too many arguments when passing array of case class

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following `case class`:

```
case class Question(content:String, answer:String)

object Question {
  implicit val format: Format[Question] = Json.format[Question]
}
```

In the controller, I am creating an object `questions` of type `Array[Question]`.

I am passing it to the view like this:

```
Ok(views.html.questions(Json.toJson(questions)))
```

However, I am getting this error when passing it:

```
too many arguments for method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class questions
```

The view looks like this:

```
import basicQG.question

@(questions: Array[Question])

@main("Answer these questions") {
}
```

Is there any other way I can pass an `Array[Question]` to the view?

Comment: It looks like the signature of `views.html.questions` doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Ok(Json.toJson(views.html.questions))`?

Comment: @m-z I Posted the signature of the view file.

Comment: Pass in the questions w/o Json.toJson? Your view seems to expect the questions rather than json.

Comment: @rethab I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error went away when I changed

```
import basicQG.question
```

to

```
@import basicQG.question
```